# Using fscanf and fprintf together in C

Tags: c, fopen, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_NAME "ff.txt"

int main() {        
    char x[10],y[10];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("couldn't find %s\n ",FILE_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         

    }
    fprintf(fp,"Hello2 World\n");
    fflush(fp);   
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s",x,y);
    printf("%s %s",x,y);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a boiled down version of what I am trying to do. This code doesn't print anything in the console. If I remove the `fprintf` call, it prints the first 2 strings in the file, for me its `Hello2 World`. Why is this happening? Even after I `fflush` the `fp`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), the file pointer points to the end of the file. You can use [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to set the filepointer at the start of the file:

```
fprintf(fp,"Hello2 World\n");
fflush(fp);   
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fscanf(fp,"%s %s",x,y);
```

Or even better as suggested by @Peter, use [`rewind()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/):

```
rewind(fp);
```

> `rewind`:
>
> The end-of-file and error internal indicators associated to the stream
>   are cleared after a successful call to this function, and all effects
>   from previous calls to ungetc on this stream are dropped.
>
> On streams open for update (read+write), a call to rewind allows to
>   switch between reading and writing.

It is always best to check the return code of [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) too.

To avoid buffer overflow, you can use:

```
fscanf(fp,"%9s %9s",x,y);
```

Comment: `rewind(fp)` is probably better, as it also has the effect (for files opened for updating) of preparing for a switch between reading and writing.